# How do to split the 2 digit numbers in a list into single digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

So I am doing an assignment in school where I am given a range of numbers and the result is basically to find the number of numbers that can be divided by a factor digit, `f`, *and* contain the "must-have" digit, `m`. So I used list comprehension in my code and I have a list that contains all the numbers in the range that can be divided by `f`. But I need help on how to make a list that only has the numbers that have the "must-have" digit `m`.

```
def find_winner(f, m, n):
     a = [x for x in range(1, n+1) if x % f == 0]
     b = list(map(int, str(a[0])))
     c = [z for z in b if z == str(m)]
     return len(c)
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of `f`, `m` and `n`, what the expected result is and what you get instead?

Comment: Just a little tip, while you may be able to understand you code, using single digit variable names makes it incredibly difficult for other people to reason about it. Although there are some common exceptions such as `i` and `n`, sacrificing a few lines for readability goes a long way.

Comment: Do you want to check how many numbers from 0-n are divisible by number f AND have a digit 'm' in them?

Comment: To check if a string contains a certain substring you can use `substring in my_string`.

Comment: `a = [x for x in range(1, n+1) if x % f == 0]` what about just `list(range(f, n+1, f))` ?

Comment: Anyway to answer the question... okay we'll go back to a variant of the list comprehension,  `[x for x in range(f, n+1, f) if str(m) in str(x)]` - in fact you might want to save `str(m)` in a separate variable first and then use that

Comment: @alani thanks so much that one worked perfectly

Comment: @Axe319 my bad, I totally forgot about that. I'll remember that next time

Answer (score -1):

Here is a rather simple way of doing this:

```
def find_solutions(numbers, factor, digit):
    solutions = 0
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if (numbers[i]%factor == 0 and str(digit) in str(numbers[i])):
            solutions += 1
    return solutions
```

If you care about the solutions then you could do this:

```
def find_solutions(numbers, factor, digit):
    solutions = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if (numbers[i]%factor == 0 and str(digit) in str(numbers[i])):
            solutions.append(numbers[i])
    return solutions
```

Please give some thought as to what is happening here as opposed to just copying it and feel free to reply if you have anything to say. By the way, I have tried to name your variables appropriately for clarity.

Comment: It looks like all three arguments to the function in the question are integers. I am not sure what your first argument (presumably a list) is meant to contain.

Comment: What is your `numbers` such that both `range(numbers)` and `numbers[i]` worked when you tested this?

Comment: I have edited it, sorry for the clumsy mistake. (I didn't test it).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you don't need to loop over all the numbers from 0 to `n` if you just want the ones that are divisible by `f`, when you can instead loop with a step of `f`.

Secondly, if you want to check whether digit is contained in the string, you could use string representation.

For example:

```
def find_winner(f, m, n):

    digit_string = str(m)

    if len(digit_string) != 1:
        raise ValueError('m must be a one-digit number')
    
    valid_numbers = [x for x in range(f, n+1, f) if digit_string in str(x)]
    
    return len(valid_numbers)
```

If you have not yet covered exceptions, you might want to replace the `raise ...` line with a `print` statement and something like `return None`.